# Reference error with ejs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am using EJS. I have two nested forEach loop and I am trying to compare if two arrays have similar values and if they do I set a variable called condition to 0 and if not condition is still 1. Here is the necessary code.

```
 <% events.forEach(function(event){ %>
       <% var condition = 1; %>
        <%  userEvents.forEach(function(userEvent){ %>
            <%  if(String(event._id) ==  String(userEvent)) condition = 0; }) %>

    <%  if(event.pointType == "Social"){ %>
```

The variable userEvents and events are passed in from the app.js file which contains the route and both variable work fine. The error that I get is that is that  userEvent(value inside the function) is not defined. For some reason when I change the following:

```
 <%  if(event.pointType == "Social"){ %>
```

to

```
` <%  if(true){ %>`
```

Here is the route:

```
    //INDEX - show all events
app.get("/event",isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
    var firstName = req.user.firstName;
    var lastName = req.user.lastName;
    var subcommittee = req.user.subcommittee;
    var userEvents = req.user.events; 

  Event.find({}, function(err, events){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
          res.render("viewEvents",{userEvents:userEvents,events:events,firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,subcommittee:subcommittee});
       }
    });
});
```

The code runs but it doesn't totally do its intended behavior.
Here is the error message:

```
    ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/views/viewEvents.ejs:25
    23|                 <%  if(String(event._id) ==  String(userEvent)) condition = 0; }) %>
    24|         
 >> 25|         <%  if(event.pointType == "Social"){ %>
    26|               
    27|             <div class="ui clearing red raised segment">
    28|                <% if(condition == 1) { %>



        userEvent is not defined
            at eval (eval at compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:111:69)
            at Array.forEach (native)
            at eval (eval at compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:24:15)
            at returnedFn (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
            at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
            at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
            at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
            at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
            at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
            at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
            at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app.js:197:15


 at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4161:16
        at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/query/completeMany.js:35:39)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I am confused as of why the error points to line 25 which doesn't even use the variabe userEvent.

Comment: Try to add quotes on your render object:res.render("viewEvents",{"userEvents":userEvents,"events":events,"firstName":firstName,"lastName":lastName,"subcommittee":subcommittee});

Comment: as in the variables I am passing in?

Comment: still have the same problem. The variables do appear in the ejs file , that's not really the problem. The problem the the argument inside the forEach

Comment: so this userEvents.forEach(userEvents){}?

Comment: What is the content of userEvents array?

Comment: I posted an answer, hope it solve the problem you are facing...

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<%  if(String(event._id) ==  String(userEvent)) condition = 0; }) %>
```

to:

```
<%  if((typeof userEvent!= "undefined" && String(event._id) ==  String(userEvent))) condition = 0; }) %>
```